# How to create connection string using parameter C#

Tags: c#, string, class, connection, layer

I am a newbie. Sorry!

My Windows Form App has 3 layer. Presentation has Form_Login with textEdit_Name and textEdit_Pass.

My Connection class:

```
public class _Connection
{
    public OleDbConnection GetConn(string _name, string _pass)
    {
        OleDbConnection _Conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};", @"C:\Test\Test.mdb", _name, _pass));
        return _Conn;
    }
}
```

My Data Access Layer:

```
public class getDAL : IDisposable
{
    private _Connection getConn = new _Connection();
    OleDbConnection _Conn = new OleDbConnection();
    public DataTable getDatatable()
    {
        _Conn = getConn.GetConn();
        //Do something
    }
}
```

How can I get _Conn with:

_name = textEdit_Name.Text and _pass = textEdit_Pass.Text

when user login through Form_Login

Comment: Do you create instance of DAL in Business Layer or Presentation Layer?

Comment: I did it in Business Layer.

Comment: That means in Form_Login you make instance of Business Layer and then in Business Layer you are creating instance of DAL? If yes then have to pass your `name` and `pass` to other layers.

Comment: Have a look at the [`OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class - this can help you create valid connection strings very easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example how you can pass `LoginForm TextBox .Text` to Business Layer and Data Access Layer.

**Data Access Layer**:

```
class DALClass : IDisposable
{
    private _Connection getConn;
    OleDbConnection _Conn;

    public DALClass()
    {
         getConn = new _Connection();
    }

    public DataTable getDatatable(string sUserName, string sUserPass)
    {
        //pass on user name and password
        _Conn = getConn.GetConn(sUserName, sUserPass);
        //Do something

        return default(DataTable);  //return datatable 
    }
}

public class _Connection
{
    public OleDbConnection GetConn(string _name, string _pass)
    {
        OleDbConnection _Conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};", @"C:\Test\Test.mdb", _name, _pass));
        return _Conn;
    }
}
```

**Business Layer**:

```
class BLClass
{
    DALClass _dal;       

    public BLClass()
    {
        _dal = new DALClass();            
    }

    public DataTable GetDataTable(string sUserName, string sUserPass)
    {
        return _dal.getDatatable(sUserName, sUserPass);
    }
}
```

**Login Form**:

```
 public partial class LoginForm : Form
 {
    BLClass _bl;

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //object of business layer
        _bl = new BLClass();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        //pass text boxes values to Business Layer      
        DataTable dt = _bl.GetDataTable(textEdit_Name.Text, textEdit_Pass.Text);            
    }
 }
```

Comment: No, it does not work... bl.sUserName and _bl.sUserPass is null when run to get connection string

Comment: @Camambeou. Sorry, I missed something obvious. Can you check my updated code?

Comment: Thanks for your idear. But it still doesn't work correctly. I don't know why. I think when we call the class is call a new one so the parameter is new too (get default value <null>)

Comment: Instances of business class and dal access are called once in the respective constructors. Notice in `LoginForm()` constructor `BLClass` instance `_bl` is instantiated.

Comment: I'm stuck, string _name and _pass always get null and application throw error "Invalid user name or password"... Do you have any idea?!

Comment: @Camambeou. Is your access db is protected with password? Do you give values in the textboxes as strings should not get `null` in any case.

Comment: My db is protected with user name and password. Password allow null. I have tried some method but useless.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have done. Project works correctly.

Comment: Can you tell me how it worked? Ok you have selected it as answer means it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest method would be to set up the ConnectionString details in a static class in your DAL.  Something like this:

```
public static class ConnectionDetails
{
    public static string UserName;
    public static string Password;

    public static string GetAccessConnectionString(string filepath)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};", filepath);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            sb.Append("User Id=admin;Password=;");
        else
            sb.AppendFormat("User Id={0};Password={1};", UserName, Password);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Your business layer needs to set the `UserName` and `Password` fields of the `ConnectionDetails` static class whenever they change in your presentation layer, and your DAL classes that need connection strings should get them by calling `ConnectionDetails.GetAccessConnectionString` with the appropriate file path.  Or add `FilePath` as one of the static fields in that class so that you can set all three from wherever.

If you're intending to use more than one database file then a dictionary of connection data keyed off the file name would probably be a good idea.

Comment: ConnectionStringBuilder is what you want here.

Comment: @HackSlash Yeah, true.  But I did write that 4 years ago.  I've moved on since then.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the ConnectionStringBuilder Class**

```
public static class BuildConnection()
{    
    public static GetConnectionString(var userName, var Password)
    {
          OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
          builder.Driver = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)";        
          builder.Add("Dbq", @"C:\Test\Test.mdb");
          builder.Add("User Id", userName);
          builder.Add("Password", Password);
          return builder.ConnectionString; // Here is your connection String 
    }
}
```